# TYPO3 fe_user: Log in as two different users at the same time possible?

Tags: typo3

One of our clients wants to FE log in as two different users at the same time, using one browser. I think this is only possible when using two different browser. IS there any workaround?

Background is this: We wrote a FE extension where user can login and update some of their data. One client is a kind of superuser/admin. He wants to compare and edit data of several users at once.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication in TYPO3 is performed by cookie **fe_typo_user** and therefore it is *not* possible to have two users logged in at same time from same browser.

You may advise to use different browsers or virtual machines for your client.

Comment: Using two different browsers would solve the problem, but that seems not to be a solution to our customer.

I was hoping for some trickery, maybe like a fe_login hook up to use several cookies or some fe_user plugin...

It's hard to tell a customer that something "is not possible"... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As **Viktor** wrote - it's not possible. Here I should finish the answer.

Anyway... while you are creating your own plugin you can easily add 'simulate mode' using for an example custom cookies... Block schema is:

```
[IF isAdmin AND simulateMode == false] {
    Display admin's version
} [ELSE] {
    Display common user's version
}
```

You can go even farther and switch the admin to simulate some chosen 'common' user, anyway make sure that will not violate some privacy police.

Comment: Thanks - I'm now thinking about using fe_groups and then do some additional handling like in your sample code. Still waiting for **the** answer though...